# How do i add Windows.Security.Cryptography in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, add-in, nuget-package

I need to use `Windows.Security.Cryptography` and `Windows.Storage.Streams` in oAuth 1a application but am not able to find any package or assembly.

Can someone please tell me how to use these two classes.

using System.Security will not allow me to import the below classes

[image]

Comment: what type of application are you creating?  web api?

Comment: I am creating a normal ASP.NET Web Application that will be doing some API requests

Comment: The `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace is in **mscorlib**.

Comment: A reference to 'mscorlib' could not be added.  This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

Comment: @SumanPalikhe - Yes, that would be true. I was trying to point out that you should already have `Windows.Security.Cryptography` available.

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography can be used in web application

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography won't let me import all the classes

Comment: @SumanPalikhe - Sorry, my mistake. I read `Windows.Security.Cryptography` as `System.Security.Cryptography`. I've given you bad advice.

Comment: Both namespaces are reserved for Windows Runtime/UWP apps, and not for ASP.NET apps. You will have to switch to .NET BCL builtin classes as others suggested.

Answer (score -2):

`Windows.Security.Cryptography` is part of the Windows SDK for windows app development. For your ASP.Net app you could add reference to [`System.Security.Cryptography`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This isn't a complete answer. You should put this as a comment under the question.

Comment: Yeah it looks like for a Windows app. I am trying to build a web system that uses oAuth 1.0 three-legged approach. So I need the libraries for encryption n posting. Is there any other I can use for Asp.net web app?

Comment: I suppose you can't directly use those classes in your asp.net app. You may have to rewrite your classes to use System.Security or if you don't want to edit too much in those classes then you can create wrapper classes (say for CryptographicBuffer) using System.Security. Either way, I believe you will have to do some work!